# Why does God appear to not know something in Supernatural?

Tags: plot-explanation, supernatural

There are a couple of episodes in Season 11 of Supernatural in which **God appears**...

> in the form of *Chuck*.

After talking about several other matters, He says that he wants to take a shower, and asks for the bathroom:

> Where's the guest room? I could use a shower.
>
> Uh, it's, um... just down the hallway --the fourth door on the left.

How can God not know? Isn't He supposed to be omniscient? (Aside from his Sister, which is a whole other topic.)

Comment: unrelated side-note: God didn't "appear as Chuck", Chuck was *always* God.

Comment: @KutuluMike I don't think I implied that. He appears to others... although it's incredible that he *faked* it ...

Comment: Perhaps it's His way of being polite. It would be rude to just shower in someone's guest room without asking. It's also possible that He's trying to distract by bringing up something irrelevant to the previous conversation. As they say, "The Lord asks for a shower in mysterious ways."

Comment: @nilon - I don't feel right posting an answer that's entirely guesswork, not having seen the show in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## God is *The Trickster's* (archangel Gabriel's) father ! ...

Many characters/scripts are developed in the series in such a way as to show how one matter or main character affects another.

---

(Maybe needless example. When we see the interaction between God/Michael and Lucifer with their respective vessels/swords in the early show it intends to show how important Sam and Dean can get to be and how they are considered in the big picture. So S & D are important because of their past, how they were raised, and so on. Likewise, some personality traits are present too when Metatron explains his, many times passive, role through all times. However he chooses something different when needed.)

---

*God being Trickster's father* may convey the idea that all his creations have some relationship to his own personality. Through season 11 He shows how **He enjoys doing several human like activities such as eating bacon and watching tv, these characteristics being pretty much alike to that of Gabriel's.** That could even consider types of porn, since Gabriel also was a bit of a fan.

Of course *politeness* (good point on another posted answer) can play a role in the God-Human interactions, but this alone may not be enough.

As an end note: **perhaps He has some pleasure in checking people's reactions**, just like the Trickster. He could just as well say:

- Hey guys I feel like taking a shower are you all cool?

Same thing but with *no need to ask for the place where it is*. As the conversation actually went, it could have been answered with some slight giggles, and

- Sure you can go, you know where it is.

  ---

Also, on the following episode, God says that He has some *guilty pleasures*. Although not sure if this may, or may not, be enough to explain why he watched xxx ...

Answer (score 3):

If you assume God's omnipotence/omniscience to be a given, why does he communicate with anyone at all?

Why does he use his voice, or even English? Why does he need a physical representation?

Also, why do we (adults) use simple language when we talk to a child, when we ourselves are smarter than that?

*Because it's what the other person is capable of dealing with.*

If God could do everything by himself, he wouldn't need to communicate anything with anyone. The fact that he communicates anything (or even just confirms his existence) means there is a purpose to it. He needs them to understand, and is therefore explaining it (and himself) in a way that is easily understandable. Demons use the human form to connect with humans, why shouldn't he?

Asking where the shower is is just a polite way of asking to use the shower. It doesn't have to imply that he doesn't know. I know where the coffee maker is in my friend's apartment, but I still ask him if I can go get a cup of coffee.

**Edit:** If anything, the quote actually shows that he knows the location of the shower.

> Where's the guest room? I could use a shower.

He already knows it's in the guest room (and that there is a guest room). Why doesn't he ask for the bathroom?

Comment: That's ok. And xxx?

Comment: If God created everything and is omniscient, this means that he must have foreseen the occurrence of porn and agreed to continue on with the creation. Also, him showing himself having certain weaknesses (porn in this case) could be to connect to the humans he wishes to talk to. Or it could just be that he acknowledges that desires are okay when taken in measure.

Comment: I do not agree. No need to objectify. But thanks for input.

Comment: @nilon: Yours is a personal opinion. Which is fine, but not necessarily that of the show's writers. There can exist a difference between real objectification (prostitution) and faked objectification (porn).

Comment: it's my opinion, yes. I made a question so I ponder answers/comments. If script/author says so that'd be fine, but not the  case here as far as I know. How can there be a difference in two kinds of xxx? I understand that both imply objectification.

Comment: It's the same as watching a movie where people die versus actually hiring gladiators to kill eachother (or hiring someone so you can kill them). One is real, the other is a reenactment and only real in the mind of the viewer (temporarily for entertainment's sake). If God had spoken out to love visiting prostitutes (and objectifying them) as opposed to watching porn, that would have turned a funny remark into a rather deep one.

Comment: so the viewer is objectifying. That's my point. Plus the girl actually gets f'd.

Comment: @nilon perhaps you are just injecting your own personal opinions onto a God which does not believe them to be true? (maybe God's not nearly as much of a prude as people think?)

Comment: @KutuluMike nice input. And in fact, my point is to try to grasp that Other view